# Show a D-dim Brownian motion is a Gaussian Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am asked to show that a D-dim Brownian motion is a Gaussian Process but I am unsure on how to show a process in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a Gaussian process.

Comment: Do you know the definitions involved?

Comment: @G.Chiusole I am familiar with the definition for a Gaussian process in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in  $\mathbb{R}^d$